# GetRepository(), CreateRepository(), DeleteRepository() methods no longer exists in Nest 7.x, how to use them?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-4.5, nest, .net-4.8

I upgrade my project from .Net 4.5.2 to .Net 4.8.1 and of course nuget package "NEST" upgraded too.

In the NEST 7.X version we don't have anymore the next methods: GetRepository(), CreateRepository(), DeleteRepository().

How to use this methods if I really need to use this methods in my existing code?

```
var getRepositoryResponse = client.GetRepository(x => x.RepositoryName("repName"));
// client it's a ElasticClient object
```

I expected that after updating the new version of .NET Framework 4.8.1 I could use these methods again: GetRepository(), CreateRepository(), DeleteRepository()

Comment: Looking at using statements at following sample code which uses Repository in Core : https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-development-part4/?force_isolation=true

Comment: No @jdweng, GetRepository it was part of ElasticClient object, NEST team was delete this method and I don't know how to use this method or how change it

Comment: So they moved the library when the moved to Core.

Comment: I found the answer! Developer team was moved this methods to Snapshop object. You must use this structure: 

`var getRepositoryResponse = client.Snapshot.GetRepository(x => x.RepositoryName("repName"));`